# Simple local maximum probability

Tags: probability

Given a sequence of numbers $a_i \in R$ choosen uniformly, what is the probability that $a_i > a_{i-1}$ and $a_i > a_{i+1}$

I know that by symmetry, the answer is 1/3. I'm interested in understanding why it isn't 1/4. These are two independent events, where $P(a_i > a_{i-1}) = 1/2$ and $P(a_i > a_{i+1}) = 1/2$ which makes me think the answer is $1/2 * 1/2 = 1/4$.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

For example, if I have the sequence $a_n := 1/n$ then the event when $1 > 1/3$  is dependent of the event when $1 > 1/2$ because the probability that $1 > 1/3$ when we know that $1 > 1/2$ is $1$.

Comment: This is an example of why the events aren't independent, you can generalize to your case

Comment: My issue is that I don't see why the events are dependent. If we know that $a_{i-1} < a_i$, why is it that the probability that $a_i > a_{i+1} = 2/3$

Comment: Which is your definition of Independence and Dependence?

Comment: Defining independence as the conditional probability = unconditioned probability